# Overwriting of stack static array when the other static array overflows

Tags: c, stack

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  char A[10];
  char B[10];
  sprintf(A,"Hello");
  sprintf(B,"AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCC");
  printf("%s:%s\n",A,B);
  return(0);
}

(gdb) p &A
$1 = (char (*)[10]) 0x7fffffffe450
(gdb) p &B
$2 = (char (*)[10]) 0x7fffffffe440
(gdb) step
2: B = "AAAAAAAAAA"
1: A = "BBBBCCCCCC"
printf o/p- BBBBCCCCCCCCCC:AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCC
```

Questions-

A comes first in the stack frame and B comes later. If B is overwriting A then all the `"BBBBBBBBBB"` should go into A why A is starting from `"BBBBCCCCCCCCCC"`?

Also I want to know if I overwrite the BP, will the program terminate?

Comment: since stack grows down to up thats why A is staring from BBBBCCCCCCCCCC

Comment: Why are you guys so obsessed with undefined behaviour? No one says the compiler has to place these automatic variables in memory in a particular way. They don't even need to be in memory! There need not be a stack in C!

Comment: but A should start from "BBBBBBBBBB...."

Comment: Regarding your question about BP, if you overwrite the base pointer (BP/EBP/RBP), then your program will likely crash when `main` returns to the C library's calling code since the base pointer will point to some other memory address, instead of where it's supposed to point to return properly.

Comment: @antii haapala - I am not concerned with the order of variables i.e why i have printed the addresses of A and B. My concern here is when we start writing B and it overflows to A the the Variable A should start from the 10 B's ("BBBBBBBBBB.....")

Comment: Chrono-Here the B is 30 bytes and i think its overwriting the BP ...still the program is executing well

Comment: 'Explain UB on my system and in my environment, which you don't have'.  DCV:(

Comment: @AnttiHaapala it's likely homework.  Profs/TA's set homework like this at the start of semester to see who is cheating - the 'AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCC' strings are easy for a script to spot online with very few false positives.

Comment: @MartinJames now that's clever :D

Comment: @AntiHaapala- Its easy to ridicule people and tagging things undefined.

Comment: @SahilChodhary There are no guarantees how, where or if these arrays are stored on the stack. Apart from memory layout issues, suppose the compiler optimizes the code. The compiler might reason like "Aha, this A variable is useless, lets replace this code with `printf("%s:%s\n","Hello",B);`. Where the buffer overflow of B goes then, you can't know. If you are lucky, your program will crash & burn so you spot the bug immediately. If you are unlucky, the bug appears when you have 1 million clients of the program shipped.

Comment: That being said, it is also pointless to discuss memory layout without a specific question in mind. Some systems have stack frames, some don't. Some CPUs have up-counting stack pointers. Some systems don't even have stacks.

Answer (score 2):

Sure `B` comes "after" `A` in the stack, but the stack (often, and assumedly on your platform based on the print-outs) growns *downwards*. Notice that the address of `B` is less than that of `A`.

So an overwrite of `B` goes into `A`.

Also I think gdb is being clever and only printing 10 characters from `B`, since it prints *10*  `A`'s and there's no termination.

You can't overwrite a processor register using rogue string formatting, registers are not in memory (in general, and certainly not on x86 which you might be using).

Note that your code invokes *undefined behavior*, so it could terminate for that reason.

Comment: BP is the Base Pointer and After writing  the 10 A's in the B Variable , compiler should actually start overwring the A variable and A should start with 10 B's "BBBBBBBBBB...."

Comment: @SahilChodhary You cannot reason about undefined behavior like that. It's undefined. There is no definiiton. Of course, you can just read the actual machine code generated by the compiler to figure out in more detail what's going on on your implementation.